# Casting objects to strings

Tags: vb.net

I have recently set OPTION STRICT ON for a solution.  There is code like this:

```
dim strTest as string = objDR("FirstName") & " Smith"
```

objDR is a datareader.  I realise the quality of this code is not particularly good e.g. concatenating strings without stringbuilder and naming veriables objDR (I did not write this code).

I now have to do this (now that option strict is on):

```
dim strTest as string = cstr(objDR("FirstName")) & " Smith"
```

However, an exception is thrown if objDR("FirstName") is null.  When OPTION STRICT was set to OFF, objDR("FirstName") would be implicitly casted to an empty string.

I can resolve this problem like this:

```
dim strTest as string = "Smith"

    If not dbnull(cstr(objDR("FirstName"))) then
    strTest=strTest & " Smith"
    end if
```

Is there a better way to approach this? I came accross TRYCAST (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zyy863x8.aspx), but it always seems to CAST objDR("FirstName") to a blank string.  I believe this is because it only works with reference types?

Answer (score 2):

Given you know it's a string value then you should use the [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Dim strTest As String = objDR.GetString(objDR.GetOrdinal("FirstName")) & " Smith"
```

This would eliminate any need for casting.

Comment: Thanks +1.  Does TRYCAST not work with strings? I thought String was a reference type?

Comment: Also I have asked another OPTION STRICT ON type question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466127/cast-to-an-integer-rather-than-a-double-when-option-strict-is-on.  In case you get chance.

Comment: `TRYCAST` does work with strings and `string` is a reference type, however, it's a bit of a special type of object in .NET. I am not sure of the inner workings on `TryCast`, however, in some cases `null` is effectively treated as an empty string e.g. `null & " Smith"` would yield `" Smith"`.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'null' is a DBNull then try this

```
    Dim strTest As String = Convert.ToString(objDR("FirstName")) & " Smith"
```