# Cast to an Integer rather than a Double when OPTION STRICT is ON

Tags: vb.net

I have recently set OPTION STRICT ON for a solution. There was code like this:

```
Dim intTest As String
        If intTest = 1 Then 'line 2

        End If
```

I did not write this code.  When I changed the setting to ON the compiler suggested changing line 2 to:

```
        If CDbl(intTest) = 1 Then
```

However I changed it to:

```
If Cint(intTest) = 1 Then
```

Is there a reason why the compiler suggested casting to a Double rather than an integer?

Comment: There is a reason why you keep around a string instead of using an integer? No Cxxx required.

Comment: Because the compiler is picking a data type that will accommodate the many ways a number could be represented.  You might consider using Integer.TryParse if the string has not been validated.

Comment: It simply recommend the same thing it does when you compile with Option Strict Off.  It is a programmer's job to judge whether that's good advice, the compiler cannot know.

Comment: @Hans Passant, does this mean that when option strict was set to off, the compiler casted to a double when compiling the code? I guess there could be a performance gain.

Comment: What ''may'' be a performance gain is avoiding the casts altogether and always using Option Strict in the first place. Casting to integer or double will probably make no discernible difference.

Comment: @jens, thanks. Would the compiler cast the string in my op to a double when option cast is set to off?

Comment: There's no casting going on here. When you cast you do not change the type of the object; only the type of the reference used to access the object. This is a conversion because the type of the data is changing. A `String` cannot be compared to anything other than a `String`. If you have a `Double` or an `Integer` then, in order for a comparison to be performed, something has to be converted to a different type. `CInt` and `CDbl` will both do that.  As suggested, you should use the proper data type for the data to begin with.  You know whether the data represents an `Integer` or a `Double`.